# Checking whether a number exist in the same row or column matrix

Tags: c

I want to output Yay if the matrix doesn't contain the same number on the same row or column otherwise output Nay

this is for my college homework. I already tried to check the column and row in the same loop but the output still not right

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size;
    int flag;
    scanf("%d",&size);
    char matrix[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < size; l++)
        {
            scanf("%s",&matrix[i]);
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++){
            if(matrix[j] == matrix[j+1] || matrix[j][k]==matrix[j][k+1])
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        printf("Nay\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Yay\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect to output "Nay" when I input

```
3
1 2 3
1 2 3
2 1 3
```

and "Yay" when i input
    3
    1 2 3
    2 3 1
    3 1 2

Comment: cyril caro, Why repeatedly read into the same place with `scanf("%s",&matrix[i]);`?

Comment: `"%s"` will attempt to read a string. To read numbers, declare the matrix as an array of `int`, and use `"%d"`.

Answer (score 0):

Your have a logic problem. Your flag is reset on every element in the matrix and thus only reflects the result of the last check.

In addition, you need a `break;` in your nested loop. The logic is, if your `flag` becomes `1`, you are sure to say `Nay`, and you don't want the `flag` to be reset to `0`.

```c
int flag = 0;
for (int i = 0; i != size && !flag; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j != size; ++j) {
        if ( /* detection */ ) {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (flag)
    printf("Nay\n");
else
    printf("Yay\n");
```

Note: The commented `/* detection */` part requires more work. *Since it's your homework, you may try it first. You could use a hash table for memorization. Or brutal force to make the program simply work. It seems that your detection only checks for neighboring elements, which is not sufficient to assert that an element is unique in its row or column. Consider*

```
1 2 1
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

**I can't do your homework for you.** The following is the brutal-force way you may consider.

The `if ( /* detection */ )` part could be `if (has_same_element(matrix, i, j))`, with a function (pseudo code)

```c
int has_same_element(matrix, row, col)
{
    for each element a in matrix's row except matrix[row][col] itself
        if (a == matrix[row][col])
            return 1
    for each element b in matrix's col except matrix[row][col] itself
        if (b == matrix[row][col])
            return 1
    return 0
}
```

*Of course there are smarter ways, like using a hash table, in which case you don't even need the nested loop. For the time being, work out a feasible solution, instead of the best solution.*

Comment: what is the purpose of that !flag i mean is it the same with the break;

Comment: `break` breaks out of only one layer of loop, in this case the inner loop. In the outer loop, once the program sees `flag == 1`, it will end the outer loop as well. So `!flag` is one of the conditions for the outer `for` loop to continue -- in this mean it requires `flag` to be `0`.

Comment: I still can't find the correct detection cause it needs to check all both row and column so the matrix is unique, do I need to make some 2nd loop just to check the column. it just likes playing sudoku but there's no rule for differences in 1 square matrix only row and column must have a different number

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix is a 2D array and you are referencing it using only a single subscript `matrix[index]` at several places which returns the address of the row. Index it using both the row and column indices. Try the code below:

```
{
    int size;
    int flag;
    scanf("%d",&size);
    char matrix[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < size; l++)
        {
            scanf("%s",&matrix[i][l]);
        }
    }
for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
    for (int k = 0; j < size; j++){
            if(matrix[j][0]== matrix[j][k] || matrix[k][0]==matrix[k][j])
            {
                flag = 1;
                 break;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        printf("Nay\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Yay\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: from the above comment I realize that the flag always been reset so I add break; and now I need some new detection because the current detection still not working